# VS2008 Detected Dependencies - Versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, installation, dependencies

After building my project on two different machines, my setup project seems to inject microsoft_vc90_mfc_x86.asm dependencies with different versions. My local machine uses version 9.0.21022.8 while the build machine uses 9.0.30729.1.

I've checked the Visual Studio versions and they are both 9.0.30729.1 SP. The build machine has some hotfixes and my local machine has VS2005 installed as well. Is there any known issue that might cause my local machine to insert the 9.0.21022.8 version?

Both installers seem to work on all my test targets, but it makes me nervous that the build machine produces a different sized installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local machine uses the RTM version, your build machine uses the SP1 version.  It really sounds like you don't have SP1 installed on your local machine.  Note that both versions are obsolete, the current version is 9.0.30729.4148.  A security patch that was distributed last July.  You can get it [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=294de390-3c94-49fb-a014-9a38580e64cb&displaylang=en).